# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: TypeSys.UI._Timer has already been registered

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, timer, dom-events

I am getting this error every time I run the page. What could be wrong?

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: TypeSys.UI._Timer has already been registered.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug that will be fixed in the next release. Basically, it has to do with how the PageRequestManager detects which scripts have already been loaded on the page

[see this link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1128011/1779819.aspx)